# How to create a MySQL stored aggregate function?

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions, stored-functions

I need to write a stored function that does an aggregate operation on a column. Let's say a median (but actually, there are many different summary functions I want to implement). Ideally, I would like to have something like `medBy( col1 col2 col3 )` which then for each row returns a median of the col1 values of all the rows that have the same col2 and col3 value as this one. That way, I wouldn't have to do `GROUP BY` on the whole query, just have a repeating value in that one column.

This question ( [How to write the quantile aggregate function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7658937/how-to-write-the-quantile-aggregate-function) ) asked something similar, but it got answered with a query rather than a stored function.

What I would like to know is what the syntax is for specifying that the stored function should operate on the whole column `col1` and the current row's values of `col2` and `col3`.

---

@djacobson: all the examples for stored functions I see treat each parameter as a single, scalar value. Maybe the question I should be starting with is how to declare an aggregate stored function at all. So, let's say I just want a function that looks like this: `medBy(col1)` and that returns the median of the column specified in the argument. Once for each row. So if I do `SELECT col1 my_values, medBy(col1) my_median FROM foo` I will get a column of values (`my_values`) and a column that is just the repeating median of the first column (`my_median`).

Thanks.

Comment: So you want an aggregate function that operates on multiple columns as well as multiple rows... Don't think I've ever seen that.

Comment: Doesn't seem that off-base: just aggregate the function's first parameter while grouping or filtering by the second and third... unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have to write a native shared library in C or C++ to pull this off.
Take a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-function-udf.html

Comment: Yes, UDF are needed to create custom aggregate functions.