# Difference between ntile and cut and then quantile() function in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I found two threads on this topic for calculating deciles in R. However, both the methods i.e. `dplyr::ntile` and `quantile()` yield different output. In fact, `dplyr::ntile()` fails to output proper deciles.

**Method 1: Using ntile()**
From [R: splitting dataset into quartiles/deciles. What is the right method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26273892/r-splitting-dataset-into-quartiles-deciles-what-is-the-right-method?noredirect=1&lq=1) thread, we could use `ntile()`.

Here's my code:

```
vector<-c(0.0242034679584454, 0.0240411606258083, 0.00519255930109344, 
  0.00948031338483081, 0.000549450549450549, 0.085972850678733, 
  0.00231687756193192, NA, 0.1131625967838, 0.00539244534707915, 
  0.0604885614579294, 0.0352030947775629, 0.00935626135385923, 
  0.401201201201201, 0.0208212839791787, NA, 0.0462887301644538, 
  0.0224952741020794, NA, NA, 0.000984952654008562)

ntile(vector,10)
```

The output is:

```
ntile(vector,10)
5  5  2  3  1  7  1 NA  8  2  7  6  3  8  4 NA  6  4 NA NA  1
```

If we analyze this, we see that there is no 10th quantile!

**Method 2: using quantile()**
Now, let's use the method from [How to quickly form groups (quartiles, deciles, etc) by ordering column(s) in a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126326/how-to-quickly-form-groups-quartiles-deciles-etc-by-ordering-columns-in-a) thread.

Here's my code:

```
as.numeric(cut(vector, breaks=quantile(vector, probs=seq(0,1, length  = 11), na.rm=TRUE),include.lowest=TRUE))
```

The output is:

```
 7  6  2  4  1  9  2 NA 10  3  9  7  4 10  5 NA  8  5 NA NA  1
```

As we can see, the outputs are completely different. What am I missing here? I'd appreciate any thoughts.

Is this a bug in `ntile()` function?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In `dplyr::ntile` `NA` is always last (highest rank), and that is why you don't see the 10th decile in this case. If you want the deciles not to consider `NA`s, you can define a function like the one [here](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/774) which I use next:

```
ntile_na <- function(x,n)
{
  notna <- !is.na(x)
  out <- rep(NA_real_,length(x))
  out[notna] <- ntile(x[notna],n)
  return(out)
}

ntile_na(vector, 10)
# [1]  6  6  2  4  1  9  2 NA  9  3  8  7  3 10  5 NA  8  5 NA NA  1
```

Also, `quantile` has 9 ways of computing quantiles, you are using the default, which is the number 7 (you can check `?stats::quantile` for the different `type`s, and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1463249/7248543) for the discussion about them).

If you try

```
as.numeric(cut(vector, 
               breaks = quantile(vector, 
                                 probs = seq(0, 1, length = 11), 
                                 na.rm = TRUE,
                                 type = 2),
               include.lowest = TRUE))
# [1]  6  6  2  4  1  9  2 NA  9  3  8  7  3 10  5 NA  8  5 NA NA  1
```

you have the same result as the one using `ntile`.

In summary: it is not a bug, it is just the different ways they are implemented.